# Cent OS 7 / 8 avoid writing media files in a specific folder

Tags: permissions, centos, samba, centos-7

I'm looking for the solution on how to restrict some of the users writing or saving media files like MP3, MP4, JPEG and other files that is related to media in their dedicated folder.

I'm using a samba server for the file server and I added some users to access the server. Every user has their own folder with the permission of RWX to the owner, RX to the group and no permissions to other users.

After modifying their folder I want to avoid saving media files on their folder.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a method to prevent saving a specific file type within a directory, but you could create a cleanup script to "remove" unauthorized files from specific folders and set a cron job for it to run every X time period.  Or instead of remove, could email, copy, etc. on the files.